# Collapsible tab with plus and minus sign

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please I need help on how to pull the plus and minus sign to the right.
Your help is highly appreciated.
Below is the url:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var $active = $('#accordion .panel-collapse.in').prev().addClass('active');
  $active.find('a').prepend('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>');
  $('#accordion .panel-heading').not($active).find('a').prepend('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>');
  $('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    $('#accordion .panel-heading.active').removeClass('active').find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
    $(e.target).prev().addClass('active').find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
  })
});
```

Comment: Can you post your full code in JSBin, codepen or something like that so we can see it action.

Comment: To the right of what? We need to see your HTML. Please read this: [MCVE]